# C# condition not triggering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a (probably silly) beginner issue in Unity.

I have this code in `Update` for a script attached to an orbiting planet:

```
Debug.Log(this.transform.position.x);
if (!Math.Sign(this.transform.position.x).Equals(Math.Sign(lastx)) {
  Debug.Log("Bang!");
}
this.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, OrbitSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
lastx = this.transform.position.x;
```

where the condition is apparently never triggering. It is supposed to trigger whenever the sphere crosses y=0 axis; aka, the sign changes.

However, the Debugging log output confirms that the sign of X is changing. Am I making some obvious error?

Comment: Use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) for this. `if(Mathf.Approximately(this.transform.position.x,lastx))`.....

Comment: @Programmer no he's not comparing the two values; he's comparing the signs of the two values. (See my answer.)

Comment: Yup, I missed the `Math.Sign` path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to take `lastx = this.transform.position.x` *before* you change the right-hand side. As you have it now, `lastx` is always equal to `this.transform.position.x` when you do the comparison.

Also, there's no need to use `.Equals()`. Just use `!=` .

```
Debug.Log(this.transform.position.x);
if (Math.Sign(this.transform.position.x) != Math.Sign(lastx) {
  Debug.Log("Bang!");
}
lastx = this.transform.position.x;
this.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, OrbitSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: This is the solution. I was worried about Java-ish == object comparison issues, but that wasn't the culprit.

Comment: Unlike Java, C# has operator overloading. You can even use `==` with strings (and many other types).